# location expression for a slash followed by a question mark

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have an access log entry with a "/" immediately followed by a "?"

```
   "/?pp=env"
   "/?2bhT6ue7ZlYpD0rLyaMsKO4iPy4= <snip>"
   "/?2bhUqOt4gXp952HAfQ9G4ggBTNQ= <snip>"
   "/?rest_route=/wp/v2/users/"
   "/?search==%00{.cookie|UI19tE|value%3dCVE-2014-6287.}"
   "/?author=1"
   <many more of these>
```

Note: there are many of these and it would be great if they can all be matched with one regex.

I have used this technique and it works great:

```
    location /index.php {
        if ($arg_title = Main_Page) {
            return 302 $scheme://$host/home;
        }
        <many more here>
```

But when I tried:

```
    location ~ ^/\?.* {
        rewrite ^ /unknown/ permanent;
    }
```

no luck.

Comment: You don't need to match what is after `?` by regex, so `location / {` should work as part after `?` is not a `request path`, but just `query parameters`

Comment: Thanks that gave me the clue I needed,

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
location / {
        if ($args ~ ^.+$) {   # match an arg with any characters in it
           rewrite ^ /unknown/ permanent;
        }

        ...snip...
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
}
```

It still matches normal URLs and handles bad URLs as well:

```
   myhost/home    # pages in my site don't have args
   myhost/        # the ending slash navigates to home page 
   myhost         # also navigates to home page
   myhost/?crap=x # navigates to /unknown/
```